# How to get Total and Percentage in MDX - Power Pivot

Tags: mdx, powerpivot

I want to get the total per year and the percentage in MDX from this dataset... any ideas, thanks.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwvgD.jpg)

Comment: please add the mdx you have attempted - as it stands the answer to this question is "read a book" or "search on Google" but if you add some code, or add a description of the dimensions & hierarchies available in your cube, to make the question more specific then maybe we can help. I thought `PowerPivot` used `DAX`?

Comment: You need to work on DAX when you talk of PowerPivot.